# How would you test something that filters complex objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, chain-of-responsibility

I have a persistent object with 7 pertinent fields.

The fields can hold the number of values listed here:

```
Field    # of Possible Values
1        5
2        20
3        2
4        2
5        19
6        2
7        8
```

Which is a potential for 121600 unique objects.

The code under test is a number of filters that grab a certain number of these objects based on the values of their fields, and then puts them in a bin for use by another system. The bin depositing is trivial, tested, and works properly... it's just that the filtering isn't working. There seems to be many edge cases that aren't being covered and many objects are being placed in a bin when they shouldn't be selected at all or vice versa.

All in all, there are 9 filters which operate in a chain of responsibility, each filter putting objects in a bin until the bin is full, at which point the chain exits. The last filter in the chain is simply a 'filter' that sends an e-mail to an admin noting that the objects are running low (ie, if the chain reached this filter, then the bin isn't full, and something needs to be looked at).

So my problem is this: How do I test these filters? I could create one of each unique type of object using a series of for statements:

```
public void FixtureSetup()
{
    for(each possible value for field 1)
    {
        for(each possible value for field 2)
        {
            // ... continue with 5 more for statements

            // Create Object with each value
        }
    }
}
```

But trying to manually figure out what objects should be properly filtered from the resulting collection (even the collection of filtered objects) would be terribly difficult (and if possible, I would have easily done it when I first wrote the filters).

I'm aware that the requirements are at fault because they say something like:

```
filter 1 gets
    - field 1: values 1/2/3
    - field 2: values 2/3/4
    - etc.
```

but the results are showing so many edge cases, that each time I change it to include that particular case, something else breaks (and I have no regression tests to ensure that it doesn't) and it's difficult to find out where in the chain the particular issue occurred.

edit> I am trying to test the filters separately, however assume the following:

filter 1 grabs 500 of the 121600 possible objects (according to the filter's criteria). I'm finding that, say 100 (complete guess) of those objects that are grabbed, shouldn't be - and for varying reasons. In order to know, I'd have to go through each one with the user(s) of the other system to know if the result set of each filter is correct. The opposite to that also lingers in my mind... what about all of the object that should have been grabbed, but weren't.

I'm starting to think that this might be a problem in requirements gathering, and not testing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you do not have a clear spec. If you don't have a clear spec then how can you possibly know whether the code works according to spec?

Take a step back. Start by writing a **one sentence spec**:

**The FrobFilter component takes a sequence of Frobs and places each one in the correct FrobBin until one bin is full.**

OK, now you've got a specification. It's not a testable or implementable specification yet. Why not? Two reasons.

Reason One: the consequence of no FrobBin filling up before the Frob sequence runs out has not been specified.

Reason Two: "correct" is not specified.

Now write a one-sentence spec that addresses each concern.

**If the sequence ends before some bin is full then the administrator is notified.**

**The correct bin for a Frob such that Blargh is Gnusto is always the FrotzBin.**

OK, now you have two more problems. How is the administrator notified? And what happens if the Frob's Blargh is not a Gnusto?

Just keep on breaking it down, one sentence at a time, until you have a complete and accurate spec. Then you'll find that **your spec, the program which implements, and the test cases all look remarkably like each other**. And that is an awesome situation to be in.

Comment: Just to update you Eric: I did in fact do this, and was able to better define the problem and its solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you should be testing each of these filters separately, with a mock filter "underneath" each one to be chained to.

Hopefully each of the filters is simple, and can be tested simply.

I'd then have a few integration tests for the whole thing when it's all wired up.

Comment: The filters are simple, but day by day, they're increasing in complexity to the point where managing that complexity is killing me.

Comment: All the more reason to keep the filters under test individually, one could argue.  Good luck!  :)